# Ionic & Angular JS - How to do a multiple step form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've search a lot in Google a solution for do a multiple step form in Ionic (In one view).

I want all data will be retrieved at end in only one submit button for my database (I use Firebase).

I don't found solution and I test a lot, but without success ...
Thanks for your time !

EDIT : I've test a Slide solution, but the button next don't work ... This is my code.

HTML :

```
<ion-slide-box>
<form style="height:100%;" ng-submit="submitEvent(event)">
<button ng-click="slideNext()" style="positon:relative; top:90px;">Next</button>
<ion-slide class="has-header">

  <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background : transparent; text-align:center;">
  <i class="fa fa-edit fa-4x" id="iconstep-ajust"></i>
  <h4 class="text stable" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 50px;  font-family: lobster;">L'événement</h4>
  </div>
  <img id="separation-step" src="img/line.png"></img>
  <div class="list" style="top:80px;">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">   
    <input type="text" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 22px;text-align:center;" placeholder="Nom de l'événement" ng-model="event.nameid">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <textarea style="color:#FFF;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);" placeholder="Description de l'événement" ng-model="event.descriptionid"></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide  class="has-header">
  <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background : transparent; text-align:center;">
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-4x" id="iconstep-ajust"></i>
  <h4 class="text stable" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 50px;  font-family: lobster;">Date/Heure</h4>
  </div>
  <img id="separation-step" src="img/line.png"></img>
  <div class="list" style="top:80px;">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="date" placeholder="EEE - MMM - yyyy" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" ng-model="event.startdateid" placeholder="Date de début">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="time" placeholder="HH:mm:ss" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" ng-model="event.starthourid" placeholder="Heure de début">
  </label>
</div>
<button class="button button-positive" type="submit" value="Add Event" style="position: relative; top: 90px;">Add</button>

</ion-slide>
```

Controller JS:

```
myApp.controller('Step1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Event', 'Auth', '$rootScope', '$state', '$firebaseArray', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', function($scope, Event, Auth, $rootScope, $state, $firebaseArray, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

 $scope.slideNext = function() {

        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    }

$scope.submitEvent = function(event) {

    var eventRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events");
    Event.add(event).then(function (data){ 
      $scope.event = [{userid : null, nameid: null, descriptionid: null, adressid: null, cpid: null, townid: null, startdateid: null, enddateid: null, starthourid: null, endhourid: null}];
     });

  }



  $scope.deleteEvent = function(index) {
    $scope.events.splice(index , 1);
  }

  $scope.auth = Auth;

    // any time auth status updates, add the user data to scope
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      $scope.authData = authData;
    });

    $scope.create = function() {
    $state.go('tabstep');
};
$scope.close = function() { 
     $state.go('tabdash'); 
};
}]
```

)

Service JS :

```
myApp.factory("Event", ["$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject", function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
var eventRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Events/');
var userRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Users/');
var events = $firebaseArray(eventRef);

     var Event = {

         all: events,

         get: function (event){
          var eventInfo = $firebaseObject(eventRef);
          event.startdateid = new Date(event.startdateid);
          event.starthourid = new Date(event.starthourid);
                return $firebaseObject(eventRef.child('Events').child(userid));

              }
            ,
        add: function (event){
          var eventInfo = $firebaseArray(eventRef, userRef);
          event.userid = userRef.getAuth();
          event.startdateid = new Date(event.startdateid).toJSON();
          event.starthourid = new Date(event.starthourid).toJSON();
                return eventInfo.$add(event);
              }
       }
       return Event;
```

PS : I'm very interested by the Ng-show/hide solution .. An example will be welcome !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using some sort of state variable (like `$step`) to dynamically show/hide different form elements using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`?

I suspect you could still keep a single form element in your HTML, but use this variable to walk a user through multiple sets of form elements. As they work through the steps they'd be updating `$scope` variables required. The final submit button would then be shown only on the final step, and would be able to use all the variables set during the previous steps.

This isn't really an Ionic specific question, so this is vanilla Angular, but with an HTML template like this:

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h2>Multi-step form demo (on step {{data.step}})</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <span ng-show="data.step == 1">
    <input id="value1" type="text" placeholder="Value1" ng-model="data.form.value1"/>
   </span>
  <span ng-show="data.step == 2">
    <input id="value2" type="number" placeholder="Value2" ng-model="data.form.value2"/>
   </span>
    <span ng-show="data.step == 3">
    <input id="value3" type="text" placeholder="Value3" ng-model="data.form.value3"/>
      <a ng-click="submit()">Submit form</a>
   </span>

    <a ng-click="nextStep()">Next</a>

  </form>

  <h2>Form data</h2>
  {{data.form}}

</body>
```

...and a controller that looks like this:

```
function ctrl($scope){
  $scope.data = {
    step: 1,
    form: {
      value1: undefined,
      value2: undefined,
      value3: undefined
    }
  }

  $scope.submit = function() {
    alert('form submitted');  
  }

  $scope.nextStep = function() {
    $scope.data.step += 1;
  }
}
```

...you can start to get what you're looking for. Obviously you'd clean up the code a bit, but this demonstrates the idea.

Here's a working codepen that shows this in action: http://codepen.io/sstorie/pen/vORoay

Comment: yep, this will work as well. @YngDev31 you could also use some directives like ng-switch to show and hide parts of the form.

Comment: That to look very interesting ! You would have to give me an example please ?

Comment: @YngDev31 Please see my updated answer for a working example.

Comment: Thank you ! And It's work with a complete DIV ? I want to hide a subtitle at each step.

Comment: Yeah, you can use the standard angular directives (like ng-show or ng-switch like @JessPatton suggested) to show whatever content you need based on what step is currently active.

Comment: It's work !! But the button next don't disappear at end. How to fix it ?

Comment: Just add an ng-show attribute to that <a> tag that considers the max number of steps in the form and only displays it if the step is below a certain value.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a slide box:
 http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/

Once they fill out the info on one page they can simply slide on over the next page to fill in (all in the same ion-view and same controller). Just use the slide delegate to handle the sliding: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/

Then on the last slide just have a submit button, use ng-model on you inputs to store values in a object such as

```
$scope.inputdata = {answerone: '', answertow: '', answerthree: ''}
```

and your html will look like:

```
<input ng-model="inputdata.answerone"></input>
```

then at the end have a submit button that fires a function on ng-click:

```
    $scope.submitdata = function(){
        var req = {
            url: yourposturl,
            method: "POST",
            data: $scope.inputdata
        }
        $http(req).success(callbackfuntion).error(callbackfunction).then(callbackfunction)
}
```

Comment: also if you want to disable slide to swipe drop this function in the controller and run it when the controller is bound. 
    $scope.slidestop = function (index) {
                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
            };

Comment: Thanks for your time. 

I've try this solution but I don't know where I can put the form balise. 
When she is in <ion-slide-box>, the SlideBoxDelegate don't work but the event is stored in database (With blank fields) . 

And when she is out of <ion-slide-box>, I've an error and the data is not stored on database (But the slide work). I'm really lost ... lol

Comment: well I have used this solution in a company app and it works just great, you must be having some other $scope related issues. No on can help you fix your problems unless you post some code.